# Angular provider overriden by parent module with same provider

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Let's say I have an Angular application with 2 modules:

- `AppModule`: root module of the application, contains everything that is public
- `ProtectedModule`: module for the "protected section" of the application

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ProtectedModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
@NgModule({
  ...
})
export class ProtectedModule {}
```

Also, let's say I have a simple service that is provided in the root module (thus accessible to components of both modules):

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
    constructor(@Inject(BASE_URL) private baseUrl: string) {}

    ...
}
```

This service will be used to perform HTTP requests from components of both `AppModule` and `ProtectedModule`.
As you can see, the service depends on the `BASE_URL` InjectionToken.
Depending on whether a request is made from a component in `AppModule` or `ProtectedModule`, I want this `BASE_URL` to be different

- `AppModule`: `BASE_URL = '/api/v1/public'`
- `ProtectedModule`: `BASE_URL = '/api/v1/protected'`

My question: how can I achieve this goal? If possible, with a solution that is easy to maintain (just like the provider wrong-solution was).

### Attempt 1: adding providers to both modules

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    provide: BASE_URL,
    useValue: '/api/v1/public'
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    provide: BASE_URL,
    useValue: '/api/v1/protected'
  ],
  ...
})
export class ProtectedModule {}
```

The problem is that the one defined in `AppModule` overrides the one from `ProtectedModule` everytime.
As per the documentation, this is expected:

> The service provided by the root AppModule takes precedence over services provided by imported NgModules. The AppModule always wins.

(source: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-two-modules-provide-the-same-service)

### Attempt 2: making `ProtectedModule` lazy-loaded

As per Andrei's comment, lazy-loaded modules come with their own injectors.
I made `ProtectedModule` lazy-loaded:

```
{
  path: 'protected',
  loadChildren: () => import('./protected/protected.module').then(m => m.ProtectedModule)
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work. Within the service, the resolved `BASE_URL` is still the one provided by `AppModule`. I think that this is due to the fact that `MyService` has `providedIn: 'root'` which means it is only provided by the root injector.

On the other hand, if I try to inject `BASE_URL` in a component inside `ProtectedModule`, I get the `BASE_URL` provided by `ProtectedModule`.

Comment: different injector nodes are created for different lazy loaded modules. is your protected module related to some url path, so it would be possible to lazy load it? then in its subtree provider would be overrided

Comment: You are right, it would have its own injector. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. When I try to inject the `BASE_URL` into the service I still get the one provided by `AppModule`. On the other hand, it works when I try to inject it into a component defined in `ProtectedModule`. I updated my question in consequence.

Comment: you can also create a duplicate of your service in the ProtectedModule. This duplicate will have 'protected' BASE_URL injected. just put it into providers, and new service instance will be created for lazy injector

Comment: Indeed, I provided it in `ProtectedModule` as you suggest. Not by adding it to the providers but by making it `providedIn: 'any'` as mentionned in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules
That's good enough for me. Thank you for your time.